# TestFlight In App Purchase Not In Sandbox

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, testflight, ipa

I'm currently a beta tester (Internal Tester) for an application we are building for IOS. 
We are having some issues with the in app purchase section of the application however it hasn't been consistent across all devices.

My college has an iPhone X and I have an iPhone 7 and we both run into the same issue. 
No matter how we are signed into the sandbox account (or not signed in; or turned off the device while signed in; or using a new account and only signing in when on the application) we receive the same popup when trying to test an in app purchase.

The popup is missing one "Environment [Sandbox]"

Answer (score 1):

This alert comes if you try to purchase sandbox product with real account credentials or vice versa.

Try below things -

1. Delete the app.
2. Logout from iTunes and iCloud.
3. Restart the phone and make sure you have logged out of your real account.
4. Your app must be archived with debug mode only. Production signed build with Adhoc/Release won't work with sandbox mode.

Comment: Tried steps 1-3, can you explain step 4 some more or provide a link where I can get more info? Some accounts are able to proceed with sandbox account purchase and others aren't, wouldn't all sandbox accounts not work in production mode?

Comment: Did you try to purchase in debug mode?